# Can't save the form

Tags: python, django, forms

I have problem that I can't save the form after submit button form is not saved. I only can do it in admin dashboard.

```
class EventPage(CreateView):
    template_name = 'event.html'
    form_class = RegisterToEvent
    second_form_class = UploadDocument

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.event = Event.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['event_id'])
        form.save()
        return super(EventPage, self).form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(**kwargs))

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EventPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        event = Event.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['event_id'])
        participants = Participant.objects.filter(event_id = event.id)
        context['participants'] = participants
        context['event'] = event
        if 'RegisterToEvent' not in context:
            context['RegisterToEvent'] = self.form_class
        if 'UploadDocument' not in context:
            context['UploadDocument'] = self.second_form_class
        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Event, pk=self.kwargs['event_id'])

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        if 'register_form' in request.POST:
            form_class = self.get_form_class()
            form_name = 'RegisterToEvent'
        else:
            form_class = self.second_form_class
            form_name = 'UploadDocument'
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(**{form_name: form})
```

I have two forms: RegisterToEvent and UploadDocuments. Problem is when I am trying to save Register to event form. I do not get any error, only

> [02/Nov/2015 10:29:45] "POST /event-2/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'event.views.home', name='home'),
    url(r'^about/', 'meetingsSystem.views.about', name='about'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
    url(r'^create-event/', 'event.views.create_event', name='create_event'),
    url(r'^event-(?P<event_id>[0-9]+)/$', EventPage.as_view()),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Can you do a little more research? Are your urls.py correct? Does it reach the post() function in your EventPage class?

Comment: I edited question. I think urls are correct

Comment: Are you sure your form.is_valid() return True?

Comment: Yes, I tried print test in form_valid method.

Comment: How do you perform a post request? Maybe you are using ajax to perform form submit?

Comment: no, it is just simple form ` <form class="form-inline" method='POST'  action=''>{%csrf_token%}
   {{ RegisterToEvent|crispy }}
   <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name='register_form' value="Register" />
  </form> `

Comment: @Rokas Do you need to create like a 2-step form process? If so, then you should instead use django form wizard. Besides,  `CreateView` is intended to be used with single form not multiple. You just taking the wrong approach. Maybe you can explain your use case first..